# how to convert objects in array which is already in a nested object in javaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-object

```
var pokemonName = window.prompt("Enter the pokemon details")
var pokemon = [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
        "Grass",
        "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Ice",
        "Flying",
        "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
        "num": "002",
        "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
        "num": "003",
        "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
        "Grass",
        "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
        1.2,
        1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Ice",
        "Flying",
        "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
        "num": "001",
        "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
        "num": "003",
        "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
}]

function pokemonDetails(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= pokemon.length; i++) {
        if (name == pokemon[i].name) {
            y = pokemon[i]
            for (var x in y) {
                console.log(x + " = " + y[x] + "\n")
            }
        }
    }
}


pokemonDetails(pokemonName);
```

i am trying get the pokemon detailsout but unable to get the next_evolution and pre_evolution details with the above code
so the code should be i have to give the pokemon name in the alert window prompt.
the function will check the pokemon name and it should give the full detail of that pokemon including with if it contains next evolution and previous evloution details
 can anyone please help me with that....
[outPut of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhrNS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use your function by adding `if` statement with a `for loop` on the next_evolution and pre_evolution like this:

```js
var pokemon = [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
        "Grass",
        "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Ice",
        "Flying",
        "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
        "num": "002",
        "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
        "num": "003",
        "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
        "Grass",
        "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
        1.2,
        1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Ice",
        "Flying",
        "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
        "num": "001",
        "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
        "num": "003",
        "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
}]

function pokemonDetails(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
        if (name == pokemon[i].name) {
            y = pokemon[i]        
            for (var x in y) {
            if(x === 'next_evolution') { 
              for (var z = 0; z < y[x].length; z++) {
              console.log(x + " = " + "num: " + y[x][z].num + ", name: " + y[x][z].name + "\n")
            }
            }else if (x === 'prev_evolution') {
              for (var z = 0; z < y[x].length; z++) {
              console.log(x + " = " + "num: " + y[x][z].num + ", name: " + y[x][z].name + "\n")
            }
            } else {
             console.log(x + " = " + y[x] + "\n")
            }
             
            }
        }
    }
}


pokemonDetails('Ivysaur');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your function in following way:

```
function getPokemonByName(name) {

const pokemonIndex = pokemon.findIndex((item) => item.name === name )

if (pokemonIndex > -1) return pokemon[pokemonIndex]

return 'Not Found'
}
```

Then you can call it using pokemon name.

```
getPokemonByName('Ivysaur')
```

This will give proper result.

[image]